# React-Native How to have a different state for each item

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

I have a component where when I click on an icon, I execute a function that modify a state and then i can check the state and modify the icon. In that comonent, I am mapping datas and it renders several items.
But when I click on one icon all the icons of the components change too.

Here is the code for the component

```
export default class DiscoveryComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            starSelected: false
        };
    }

    static propTypes = {
        discoveries: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    onPressStar() {
        this.setState({ starSelected: !this.state.starSelected })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.props.discoveries.map((discovery, index) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={index} style={{flex: 0}}>
                        <CardItem>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.star]}>
                                <Icon style={[styles.iconStar]} name={(this.state.starSelected == true)?'star':'star-outline'} onPress={this.onPressStar.bind(this)}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </CardItem>
                    </Card>
                )
            })
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my screen that uses the component

```
export default class DiscoveryItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        discoveries: [],
        loading: true
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.database().ref("discoveries/").on('value', (snapshot) => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        let discoveries = Object.values(data);
        this.setState({discoveries: discoveries, loading: false});
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <Container>
            <Content> 
              <DiscoveryComponent discoveries={this.state.discoveries} />
            </Content>
          </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initiation is correct but you are missing **INDEX** of each item. Inside `this.onPressStar()` method check if item's index = currentItem. Also don't forget to set item id = index onpress.

I hope this has given you idea how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn your stars into an Array and index them:

change your constructor:

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            starSelected: []
        };
    }
```

change your onPressStar function to :

```
onPressStar(index) {
    this.setState({ starSelected[index]: !this.state.starSelected })
}
```

and your icon to

```
<Icon style={[styles.iconStar]} name={(this.state.starSelected[index] == true)?'star':'star-outline'} onPress={()=>this.onPressStar(index)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you have a single 'starSelected' value that all of your rendered items in your map function are listening to. So when it becomes true for one, it becomes true for all.

You should probably maintain selected state in the top level component, and pass down the discovery, whether its selected, and how to toggle being selected as props to a render function for each discovery.

```
export default class DiscoveryItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        discoveries: [],
        selectedDiscoveries: [] // NEW
        loading: true
      };
    }

    toggleDiscovery = (discoveryId) => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        const {selectedDiscoveries} = prevstate
        const discoveryIndex = selectedDiscoveries.findIndex(id => id === discoveryId)
        if (discoveryIndex === -1) { //not found
          selectedDiscoveries.push(discoveryId) // add id to selected list
        } else {
          selectedDiscoveries.splice(discoveryIndex, 1) // remove from selected list
        }
        return {selectedDiscoveries}
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.database().ref("discoveries/").on('value', (snapshot) => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        let discoveries = Object.values(data);
        this.setState({discoveries: discoveries, loading: false});
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <Container>
            <Content> 
              {
                this.state.discoveries.map(d => {
                  return <DiscoveryComponent key={d.id} discovery={d} selected={selectedDiscoveries.includes(d.id)} toggleSelected={this.toggleDiscovery} />
              //<DiscoveryComponent discoveries={this.state.discoveries} />
            </Content>
          </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

You can then use your DiscoveryComponent to render for each one, and you're now maintaining state at the top level, and passing down the discovery, if it is selected, and the toggle function as props.

Also, I think you may be able to get `snapshot.docs()` from firebase (I'm not sure as I use firestore) which then makes sure that the document Id is included in the value. If snapshot.val() doesn't include the id, then you should figure out how to include that to make sure that you use the id as both key in the map function as well as for the selectedDiscoveries array.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It works now, thanks. 
I've made a mix between Malik and Rodrigo's answer.

Here is the code of my component now

```
export default class DiscoveryComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            tabStarSelected: []
        };
    }

    static propTypes = {
        discoveries: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    onPressStar(index) {
        let tab = this.state.tabStarSelected;
        if (tabStar.includes(index)) { 
            tabStar.splice( tabStar.indexOf(index), 1 );
        }
        else {
            tabStar.push(index); 
        }
        this.setState({ tabStarSelected: tab })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.props.discoveries.map((discovery, index) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={index} style={{flex: 0}}>
                        <CardItem>
                            <Left>
                                <Body>
                                    <Text note>{discovery.category}</Text>
                                    <Text style={[styles.title]}>{discovery.title}</Text>
                                </Body>
                            </Left>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.star]}>
                                <Icon style={[styles.iconStar]} name={(this.state.tabStarSelected[index] == index)?'star':'star-outline'} onPress={()=>this.onPressStar(index)}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </CardItem>
                    </Card>
                )
            })
        );
    }
}
```